# Punctuation - deleting commas

Tags: punctuation, commas

I have a very simple question. When we are writing compound sentences, it is possible to write sentences below.

> He was playing soccer, and while he was playing he got injured.
>
> He was playing football, and even though injured he kept playing.

So, if we can delete the comma that comes before the subject of second independent clause, why can't we say this?

> While he was playing he got injured. X
>
> While he was playing, he got injured. o
>
> Even though injured he kept playing. X
>
> Even though injured, he kept playing. o

Why can't we use the ones with X marks? Or is it actually possible/formal? Any type of explanations would be deeply appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: To the extent that the first two examples you give are valid, so are the two examples you mark with an X in your second group of examples.

Comment: So all of them, all 6 of them, are correct? I just do not know how the ones with x marks are correct because I have been taught that complex sentences need commas all the time.

Comment: It's a somewhat artificial situation, because the first two sentences are much more like transcribed spoken sentences than like carefully worded written sentences. But there is no logical (as opposed to aesthetic or visual) reason why omitting the comma after _playing_ in  "While he was playing he got injured" is different from omitting it in the same place in "He was playing soccer, and while he was playing he got injured." Aesthetically/visually, you might not want to put a second comma in a sentence that already has one (at a slightly different level), but that's a different issue. ...

Comment: So to sum up what you are saying, "While he was playing he got injured" is valid because it is a sentence rather spoken out loud than written, and the "He was playing soccer, and while he was playing he got injured" is also valid because it has already one comma in it?

Comment: ... Logically, there is a strong break after _soccer_, which you could demarcate with a semicolon: "He was playing soccer; and while he was playing, he got injured." But that sentence looks rather heavily punctuated, doesn't it? So people may be inclined to go with "He was playing soccer, and while he was playing he got injured." But logically (again) doing that puts the "and while he was playing he got injured" portion of the sentence on the same footing as the whole sentence "While he was playing he got injured." That's what I mean by its being as valid as the first two examples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are certain mandatory rules of English grammar.  If you want to indicate that someone was engaged in the game of soccer, you must follow the English grammar rules of word order and construction and say something along the lines of "He was playing soccer."  If you say, "Playing will he being soccer," you haven't said something coherent.  We can talk about "correct" and "incorrect" usage in this instance.

Punctuation rules aren't like this.  They may reflect some of the underlying grammar rules, but they are mostly conventions designed to make the written word clearer to readers.  Various and differing sets of conventions exist.  You may be directed to use one of those conventions if you write for others for a living, but otherwise which rules you follow are up to you.  In your parlance, picking X's and o's is up to you.

That said, careful writers choose rules that make their writing easy to understand, rules that keep readers from having to reparse what they read.  Introductory adverbial clauses generally have a following comma:

> While he was playing, he got injured.

This is a kindness to your reader:  among other things, the comma re-enforces the fact that no object will follow "playing," i.e., the sentence won't continue along lines of

> While he was playing soccer, ....

It's easier to teach things as "correct" and "wrong," but not everything you learn in school is the truth.

Comment: Hm... then it means that it is ok to use both "while he was playing, he got injured" and "while he was playing he got injured", but the first one with the comma is just "better" for the readers, since it provides clarity?

Comment: You'll have to ask yourself whether you readers will think it's ok.